# Wordpress SQL: Selecting posts after a certain date

Tags: sql, wordpress

Having trouble with dates. What SQL code would I use to get all posts after 01.01.2011?

```
AND post_date > XXXX
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
AND post_date > "2011-01-01"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE post_date > '2011-01-01'
ORDER BY post_date
```

something like that should work, or if you want between two dates

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01'
ORDER BY post_date
```

hope that helps

lots of good refrence here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE post_date='2008-11-11'
```

In PostgreSQL it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE post_date='2008-11-11'::date
```